# Get a preceding sibling to element?

Tags: xslt

In this flat XML how can I get a 'immediate parent' of company with given name?
I mean an element which has Level = 0 and is first element before given company.

So given that company name is V I need to get company Z.

```
<Companies>
  <Company>
     <Name>X</Name>
     <Level>1</Level>
   </Company>
   <Company>
     <Name>Y</Name>
     <Level>1</Level>
   </Company>
   <Company>
     <Name>Z</Name>
     <Level>0</Level>
   </Company>
  <Company>
     <Name>V</Name>
     <Level>1</Level>
   </Company>
</Companies>
```

This is not working?

```
<xsl:value-of select="Companies/Company[Name='V']/preceding-sibling[Level=0]/last()
```

Comment: When you say something is "not working", you should say what it actually is doing, and contrast that with what you expected it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `<xsl:value-of select="...">`, you can change

```
Companies/Company[Name='V']/preceding-sibling[Level=0]/last()
```

to

```
(Companies/Company[Name='V']/preceding-sibling::*[Level=0])[last()]
```

Note:

- The preceding-sibling axis, like any axis, must be followed by `::` and a node-test (such as `*`).
- `last()` is not what you want as a location step (though it might be legal in XSLT 2.0.... I'm not sure). Instead, you want it inside a predicate `[` `]`. The predicate `[last()]` is shorthand for `[position() = last()]`.
- The reason I put parentheses around everything before `[last()]` is a reason that @Lukasz alluded to: The `preceding-sibling::` has a reverse direction.

So if you say `preceding-sibling::*[last()]` you get the last preceding sibling in reverse order, i.e. the first preceding sibling in *document* order! Since you actually want the *last* preceding sibling in document order, you can do `preceding-sibling::*[1]` as @Lukasz did; or you can what I did with `(...)[last()]`. Both are valid. I slightly prefer the latter, as I'll explain below.

The `(...)[last()]` form works because the parentheses force the `[last()]` predicate to apply to the *whole XPath expression* up to that point, instead of to just the step that has the `preceding-sibling::` axis. As a result, the predicate is being applied to an expression that is not governed by the `preceding-sibling::` axis' reverse direction. Therefore we select the last node (of the given set) in *document* order.

Without the parentheses, in some XPath expressions, the associativity of predicates and axes can come as a surprise. You have to know a bit about precedence rules. Admittedly I'm a bit lazy about learning the details of the precedence rules. But my experience (in many programming languages) has been that relying on less-obvious rules of parsing precedence is a good way to make sure your code gets misunderstood or messed up by the next person who comes along and tries to debug or modify it. (Often that "next person" is myself, a month later.)

Answer (score 1):

The following XSLT fragment will retrieve the previous Company element from the provided sample XML:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="Companies/Company[Name='V']/preceding-sibling::*[1]" />
```

It would be:

```
<Company>
    <Name>Z</Name>
    <Level>0</Level>
</Company>
```

As you can see we're accessing **the first** node (`*[1]`)  - this might seem to be against intuition - you can find further explanation [here](http://www.infopathdev.com/blogs/greg/archive/2005/06/13/Using-XPath_2700_s-_2700_preceding_2D00_sibling_2700_-Axis-Correctly.aspx).

EDIT: I'm not sure whether you want to have the Level=0 condition taken into consideration.

Comment: Re: your "EDIT" question... I believe he does. See OP's first paragraph.